# Strange behavior of file creating in java

Tags: java, file-handling

I have this code here to create a file if not exist and write to it.Its behavior is strange.It creates it onetime and doesn't the other,no matter in which folder i make it.It could be a small mistake but i can't get my head around.
Sometimes it makes the file but it's unreadable.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\testfile.txt");
        Scanner fileScanner = null;
        try {
            fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (!file.isFile()){
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pw.println("hello world\n");
        pw.append("how si it going?\n");
        pw.append("checkingggg");
        pw.close();
       // while (fileScanner.hasNext()){
          //  System.out.println(fileScanner.nextLine());
        //}

    }
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific about the "doesn't the other" part of your question?

Comment: It is your code that is strange. You don't need to call `File.createNewFile()` when the next effective line in your program is `new PrintWriter(...)`. You are forcing the OS to test for a file, create a file, test for a file again, delete it, and create another file. Don't waste time and space like this. And code that relies on the success of code in a prior `try` block must be inside that `try` block. Don't write code like this.

Comment: It doesn't create the file or it creates it but it's unreadable.I have pasted the error above.

Comment: So you are trying to open, with `new Scanner(file)`,  a file that doesn't exist. Obviously. You are *then* (a) testing for its existence, (b) creating it, (c) testing for its existence again, (d) deleting it, and (e) creating it again. All of which is highly redundant and too late for the original open. It doesn't begin to make sense.

Comment: @EJP it's actually my ide..in my original code,i was not creating and testing..It surrounded it in try catch block and made this.. In original code,I was only throwing exception in main..

Comment: It's your code. You are responsible. Nobody else.

Comment: place that `if` block before Scanner's `try-catch` block

Comment: @Nithin You are not getting it. The `if' block can be removed entirely. It is what follows that needs to be moved.

Comment: Ok..I got it now..The problem was my Scanner definition.I Had to do it after creating and closing the file and then read from it.

Comment: That's what I said. Were you expecting time to run backwards?

Comment: @EJP Can you answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @EJP yea did not thought at that moment

Comment: You have still not grasped my original point.

Comment: @Riz please dont post answer in question. You can post it seperately as an answer

Comment: Its best in these situations to pretend to be the computer and step through each line 1 by 1 performing the action as it happens.  You'll find you're out of sequence quite early on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no strange behaviour here. You are trying to read a file that doesn't exist. You are *then* trying to create it, via a variety of redundant means, but it is already too late.

Your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Which of the method I have used is redundant?

Comment: I've answered that. See my first comment. It starts with 'you don't need to call'. The thing that you dint need to call is redundant. This seems rather obvious.

Comment: Sorry,I didnt notice well that.I didn't know `PrintWriter` creates a file if it's not there.Tested and works fine.Thank you

Comment: Of course it does, and it says so. So do `PrintStream,` `FileWriter`, and `FileOutputStream`.